# Integration Between dot Net Application With Zoho Desk?

Tags: .net, zoho

How can we possibly Integrate dot net Application with Zoho Desk.
want my Feedback Forms to Accessible in dot Net Application in Box View and we can manage our Tickets from both Ends.

One more thing we don't wan use any third party integration to achieve this, wan do that with the help of Rest API.
Is that even Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not aware, Zoho Desk provides REST API to manage things from other system. You can simply use their REST APIs from your .Net application.

Here is the link for their API documentation: https://support.zoho.com/support/APIDocument.do#GettingStarted#Errors

Hope this will help you to kick start.